# What does it mean by a 'systems language'?

Tags: programming-languages, go

The Go talk 2009 pdf has a comment to explain why they came up with the go language :

```
No new major systems language in a decade.
```

What's the meaning of systems language?

- Is it a language that is supposed to run on target system by generating native binary?
- Is it a language that can build operating system on its own?

I can see C#/Java is `not' a systems language, and C/C++ is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a rough, informal distinction, but the idea is that there are "application programming languages," targeted at programmers who develop shrinkwrapped business applications, and "systems programming languages," targeted at programmers who program tools for other programmers (compilers, etc.) and low-level software such as OS kernels, device drivers, etc.

In short, most (recently-invented, anyway) languages are designed to make it easier to develop user-facing software for dealing with some non-computing domain---finance, engineering, etc. Systems programming languages are those, such as C, FORTH, Go, etc. which are intended or at least suitable for programming in the domain of computing.

These often, but do not always, feature compilation to native code, loose type systems which permit extensive "punning," and unmanaged memory access through pointers or an equivalent construct.

Comment: I certainly do not see why unmanaged memory should be a feature here. You can have managed memory AND pointers.

Comment: @ Matthieu M.: right, but the key feature here was the unmanaged memory access, not the pointers. Think device drivers, OS kernels, etc.--- at some point you need the ability to read & write to arbitrary memory locations. Additionally, any memory-managed language allowing pointers (i.e. an arithmetic-capable type representing memory locations) will have some major run-time checks imposed, which isn't exactly what most people think of when thinking of "pointers".

Answer (score 3):

[Look here?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_programming_language) Sorry if this comes off as sorta a throw away link, but really this should be all you need. Unless you are asking for something else more specific.

A reason C# is definitely not a systems language is its dependency on .NET.

Comment: What if [a "systems programming" subset of] .NET was part of the kernel (just another boot-strap step)? ;-) Also, technically, C# doesn't require .NET (C# is just a language specification: VS/.NET is one implementation -- including useful libraries -- and Mono is a competing compiler/run-time).